# iOS Swift: is it possible to create customized in-app rating view

Tags: ios, swift, rating, skstorereviewcontroller

I have searched quite a while that it seems there is no way to customized the in-app rating view in SKStoreReviewController API. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

or do you have other options that we can write a rating view based on our own UI design and send it to App Store? Like providing a Send button, stars system, and a textfield for review message on the view?

Thanks in advance!

[image: This is the default rating view]

Comment: No definitely not. Some apps make a custom one, but they can't send the ratings to the App Store. This is because any app could just forge fake 5 star reviews.

Comment: @Asleepace Thank you very much for a quick reply. is it possible for this case like we create a very BEAUTIFUL rating view and there is a SEND button on the view. And when the users hit the SEND button, we navigate to the app store rating and review page with the review content (edited in our view) on it. And users will (have to) hit the confirmation button again on the app store page to actually send the review?

Comment: as far as I know you can’t but maybe they changed something since iOS 12

Comment: No you should use the `SKStoreReviewController` as stated in Apples HIG.  This is so that it is secure (apps can't fake it), it is consistent (you know what the app is doing as it is the same as others) and also so it's not too frequent (the review will only be presented a limited number of times which I think is 3 in 365 days).  While you may be able to go to the app store page to allow the user to review your app you can't pre-fill it with data so designing a BEAUTIFUL rating view will be a waste of time.  I suggest focusing on making the app itself as good as possible.